# Como chamar corretamente uma função através de outra função em C?

Tags: c, funções

Tenho as seguintes funções :

```
int testarDivisibilidade(int dividendo, int divisor);
int divisibilidade3(int num);
```

E as seguintes variáveis :

```
int dividendo;
int divisor;
```

Com a função `testarDivisibilidade`, eu vou verificar se o `dividendo` é divisível pelo divisor.

**Código :**

```
int divisibilidade3(int num)
{
    int res = 0;

    while( num > 0 )
    {
        res += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    if(res > 9)
        return divisibilidade3(res);
    else
        return ! (res % 3);

int testarDivisibilidade(int dividendo,int divisor) {

    if(divisibilidade3(dividendo) == 1) {
        printf("%d é divisivel por %d ", dividendo,divisor);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Eu tenho que verificar se `divisibilidade3`retorna `true` para poder então disparar a mensagem dentro do if. Mas esta dando problema, pois para todos casos do `dividendo`, ele retorna como `true`.

[image]

**Resumindo : Como posso verificar corretamente a minha função `divisibilidade3` dentro da função `testarDivisibilidade` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noto que o código exemplo que você postou não compila:

- Primeiro, na linha 12, você está chamando uma função `Divisibilidade()`, quando você certamente queria chamar `divisibilidade3()` (note o `D` maiúsculo e a falta do `3`).
- Segundo, na mesma linha 12, você está chamando a função e *descartando o resultado*: o que você efetivamente queria dizer é `return divisibilidade3(res);` Isso faz com que o compilador emita um erro que "nem todos os caminhos de código retornam".
- Finalmente, no caso base da recursão, na linha 14, você está retornando `res % 3`, que **não retorna 1 quando `num` é divisível por 3**. Em vez disso, você quer dizer `return res % 3 == 0;` ou `return ! (res % 3);`

Com essas alterações, a chamada de `divisibilidade3()` dentro de `testarDivisibilidade()` está correta e deve funcionar.

Note que, na função `testarDivisibilidade()`, você testa se `dividendo` é divisível por 3 usando `divisibilidade3()` e, sendo, emite uma mensagem dizendo que `dividendo` é divisível por `divisor`, para qualquer valor de `divisor`! Estritamente, isto está errado a não ser que você passe `3` como argumento para o parâmetro `divisor`.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, funcionou corretamente. Na verdade só irá chamar a função divisibilidade3 se o usuário escolher o divisor 3.